# Difference between "ran into someone" and "bum into someone"

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

I wonder what's the Difference between "ran into someone" and "bum into someone" or do they both mean the same . I have Heard the " ran into someone " couple of time and "bum into someone" few times (actually only once) so do it means the phrase "bum into someone" in not very common or you can only use this phrase in certain situations .

Comment: Are you sure you didn't hear "bump into someone"? "Bum into someone" is definitely not common in American English.

Comment: Or "bum off of someone".

Answer (score 2):

Both *[bump into](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bump?q=bump+into#bump__16)*  and *[run into](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/run-into?q=run+into)*
mean to 'meet someone by chance'. (Oxford dictionary definitions)

They are interchangeable.

I think I use *run into* more often. *Bump into* sounds a little old fashioned or even "weird" to me.

Answer (score 0):

**Both mean the same**= to meet someone by chance .

Being **"run into"** informal, perhaps this is the fact that makes  it much more

commonly used than **bump into**.

Comment: They are both colloquial or informal.